# Question involving polynomials and fields

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm studying *Galois Theory* and I'm stuck in a problem, let's see:

> Let $P(x) = X^5 - p \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$, where $p$ is prime. Find a Splitting field $L$ of $P$, five subfields of $L$ and the factoration of $P$ in that fields.

Now, let $\epsilon = e^{2i\pi/5}$, of course $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{p},\epsilon)$ and the subfields may be $\mathbb{Q}_i(\epsilon^i \cdot \sqrt[5]{p})$, for $i=0,1,2,3,4$.

I'm stuck on the factorization, for instance, if $i=0$ then in $\mathbb{Q}_{0}(\sqrt[5]{p})$ we can write $$P(x) = (x - \sqrt[5]{p})(x^4 + x^3(\sqrt[5]{p}) + x^2 (\sqrt[5]{p})^2 + x(\sqrt[5]{p})^3 + (\sqrt[5]{p})^4)$$

My question is:
***Is $x^4 + x^3(\sqrt[5]{p}) + x^2 (\sqrt[5]{p})^2 + x(\sqrt[5]{p})^3 + (\sqrt[5]{p})^4$ irreductible over $\mathbb{Q}_0(\sqrt[5]{p})$??***

I've tried to solve a system or thinking in Binomial Theorem, but well... I'm here. Can you give me a hint? Also, I need to find that in another four fields...

Comment: Can you find the degree of the splitting field? That, and the Tower Law, may help you solve your problem.

Comment: The degree is 20... I tought about that, but I did't see the solution

Comment: You have a tower $L,K,{\bf Q}$ where $K={\bf Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is any one of the five fifth roots of $p$. You know the degree of $L/{\bf Q}$ and of $K/{\bf Q}$, so you know the degree of $L/K$. Now the other key piece is that if $\beta$ is any one of the other fifth roots of $p$, then $L=K(\beta)$ (why?). That gets you very close to solving your problem.

Comment: I know how to prove all your statements, but honestly I didn't see how to use that to prove that $x^4 + x^3(\sqrt[5]{p})^2 + x^2 (\sqrt[5]{p})^3 + x(\sqrt[5]{p})^4 + p$ is irreductible.... Can you be more clear? Also, I know that there is not roots of this polynomial in  $K$

Comment: $L=K(\beta)$, and $[L:K]=4$, so $\beta$ is of degree four over $K$, so the minimum degree of a polynomial over $K$ vanishing at $\beta$ is four, so your polynomial of degree four vanishing at $\beta$ is irreducible over $K$.

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have $x^4 + x^3(\sqrt[5]{p}) + x^2(\sqrt[5]{p})^2 + x(\sqrt[5]{p})^3 + (\sqrt[5]{p})^4 = (x-\sqrt[5]{p}\epsilon)(x-\sqrt[5]{p}\epsilon^2)(x-\sqrt[5]{p}\epsilon^3)(x-\sqrt[5]{p}\epsilon^4)$ implies if one of the linear reducible factor lies in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{p})$ then $5th$ primitive root of unity also lies in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{p})$ which is not true. Then we have only possibility left is degree 2 irreducible factors. As none of the $5th$ primitive roots of unity lies in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{p})$, so we can club the roots $\sqrt[5]{p}\epsilon$ and $\sqrt[5]{p}\epsilon^4$ together and see whether $x^2 - \sqrt[5]{p}(\epsilon + \epsilon^4)x + (\sqrt[5]{p})^2$  but $(\epsilon + \epsilon^4) \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{p}) $ as if you adjoin $\epsilon + \epsilon^4$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ the resulting field have even dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$. So the polynomial $x^4 + x^3(\sqrt[5]{p}) + x^2(\sqrt[5]{p})^2 + x(\sqrt[5]{p})^3 + (\sqrt[5]{p})^4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[5]{p}]$.